# HOW TO CREATE a multy MAP for 3 data sets

Tags: c++

I have a huge amount of data set. I wish to use array to store these data. In more deatil,

In my array, i want to use 3 columns such as `Number   number_of_points  point_numbers`. For this i can create a array like `mypointstore[][]` (for example `mypointstore[20][3]`). But my problem is that i want to store point numbers in column 3 like, `20, 1, 32, 9, 200, 12` and etc.(`mypointstore[0][0]= 1`, `mypointstore[0][1]= 6` and `mypointstore[0][2]={ 20, 1, 32, 9, 200, 12 }`). I don’t know that is it posible to use array for this structure? If so, please help me to solve this problem.

I tried to use map like `map<int,int,vector<int>> mypointstore;` but i don’t know how to insert data into this map;
My some codes are here

```
map<int,int, vector<int>> mypointstore;
size=20;
For (int i=0; i<= size;i++){
Int det=0;
    For (int j=0; j<= points.size();j++){//points is a one of array with my points
        If (points.at(j)>Z1 && points.at(j) <=Z2){
    //Here i want to store i , det and poiznts.at(j) like i in 1st colum, det in 2nd and
     //pointnumber in 3rd colum) in each step of the loop it take a point                                                                                                                                                                                                 
     //number   //which satisfied the if condition so it should be include into my    
     // vector of map   
det++;
}
}
    // at here i want to change total det value into 2nd element of my map so it like (0)(6)( 20, 1, 32, 9, 200, 12)
}
```

similar procedure for the next step so finaly it should be

```
(0)(6)( 20, 1, 32, 9, 200, 12)
(1)(10)( 20, 1, 32, 9, 200, 12, 233, 80, 12, 90)
(2)(3)( 3, 15, 32)
```

Comment: I have tidied up your post a little, but not your code. You have several bugs. `For` not `for`, `Int` not `int`, `If` not `if`, `>>` not `> >`, very poor indentation, too many template arguments to `std::map` (`vector<int>` is not a comparator).

Comment: no i don#t konw how to post codes here

Comment: There's a whole bunch of advice, information and links to more on the right-hand-side of the box where you wrote your question. And the issues I describe are about _the code itself_.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you probably want a vector of structs, something like:

```
struct point_data { 
    int number;
    std::vector<int> point_numbers;
};

std::vector<point_data> points;
```

I've only put in two "columns", because (at least as I understand it) your `number_of_points` is probably `point_numbers.size()`.

If you're going to use the `number` to find the rest of the data, then your idea to use a `map` would make sense:

```
std::map<int, std:vector<int> > points;
```

You could use a `multimap<int, int>` instead of `map<int, vector<int> >` but I usually find the latter more understandable.

Comment: Actually number_of_points is not a point_number.size(), sorry i miss 1 line after 2nd loop that is condition values Z1 and Z2 will be change.

Comment: @nah: perhaps @dark_charlie's (implicit) suggestion is right, and you should edit the question so we stand a better chance of figuring out what you really want.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "vector of structs". The vector contains objects.